# Apache Spark SQL Documentation

Tags: apache-spark, documentation, apache-spark-sql

Does anyone know where something close to documentation for the SQL that Apache Spark implements?  I mean an extensive listing of every operator, library function, keywords, etc.  Similar to Microsoft and T-SQL. I am doing kind of trial and error right now

Comment: If you're working with pyspark then here's the link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html  These functions would be very similar to the ones implemented in Java and Scala

Comment: I don't want the scala or java or python. I wanted the SQL.  When you have an SQL expression.

Comment: Your best bet is to go to look at the documentation for Hive. Spark's SQL comes from Hive.

Comment: There is absolutely no room for interpretation in this question, if read properly and understood properly.   There is simply no official online manual for Spark SQL, and I was asking for verification on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@David Griffin* said in comment, Spark SQL comes from Hive.

And on [Spark's website](http://spark.apache.org/sql/), it says:

> Spark SQL reuses the Hive frontend and metastore, giving you full
>   compatibility with existing Hive data, queries, and UDFs. Simply
>   install it alongside Hive.

So you should look into [Hive Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual)

Comment: That's not complete though tbh.  What version of Hive does Spark align with for each version of Spark.